# how to break out of loop when while mocking

Tags: mocking, mockito, powermock

I have a piece of code which goes like this:

```
while(count = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
    //do something
}
```

In unit test case I'm mocking `inputStream.readLine()` and returning a string but, in this case, it will go in infinite loop as every time it will return a string

Comment: Simply don't return a string but null in the mock. Otherwise, If this is C#, then you can replace your loop with File.ReadAllLines and the problem are gone.

Comment: then i wont be able to cover the code inside loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can provide multiple returns when training your mock, the last one of which can be null:

```
when(inputStream.readLine()).thenReturn("one", "two", "three", (String)null);
```